# Replace unique character to array

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I need replace all occurrence of `#` on subject by an array of characters. For instance:

```
Input: "#### #### #### ####"
Search character: "#"
Replacement array: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 ]
Expected result:  "0000 1111 222 3333"
```

I tried to use:

```
str_replace("#", $array, $subject)
```

But it doesn't work as I want it to. Any ideas?

Comment: What language is the code written in?

Comment: Wait , you have a `string` with some "#" and you want to replace each "#" by an `array`?

Comment: PHP. Yes, except if I have a better method.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and access your replacement array and replace each match with a new element, e.g.

```
<?php

    $input = "#### #### #### ####";
    $replacement = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    $key = 0;
    $output = preg_replace_callback("/#/", function($m)use(&$key, $replacement){
        if(isset($replacement[$key]))
            return $replacement[$key++];
        else
            return $replacement[$key = 1];
    }, $input);

    echo $output;

?>
```

output:

```
0000 1111 2222 3333
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, so I can improve my answer. I think my answer shows OP exactly how to do what he wants.

Comment: @Rizier123: Remove `$key+1` and it works fine / Edit: looks like you fixed it just as I commented

Comment: @splash58 Didn't noticed that after I updated my code. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't a simple for loop do the trick?

```
function replacer($array,$item, $subject){

   foreach($array as $character)
      $subject=preg_replace('/'.$item.'/',$character,$subject,strlen($item));

   return $subject;
}
```

Test

```
$input = "#### #### #### ####";
$replacement = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3];

echo replacer($replacement, '#',$input);
```

Output

```
0000 1111 2222 3333
```

Comment: *Why can't a simple for loop do the trick?* Most probably, because this will throw you an error and also doesn't work:  http://3v4l.org/65Yeq

Comment: Seriously who upvoted this? It does not even works and throws an error!

Comment: Yep. I knew that. Made some edits too quick and posted too quick. It should work right now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a simple `for`.

```
$subject = "#### #### #### ####";
$numbers = "0000111122223333"; // I could use array, instead
$numbersLength = strlen($numbers);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numbersLength; $i++) {
    $subject = preg_replace("/#/", $numbers[$i], $subject, 1);
}
```

I don't think that is an elegant solution, but seems that PHP don't have a native method to do it.